# Modifying HTTP GET Request via Select Menu Change - Update Parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a search results page in a PHP site that returns a list of results using pagination. The URL looks like this:

```
findProducts.php?action=searchAssets&orderNumber=xxxx&productName=zzz&skip=20
```

I have a select menu that allows the user to modify/filter the search results which triggers a script like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#productType').change(function() {
    window.location.href = window.location.href + '&productType=' + $(this).val();
  });
});
```

This is working well except for one thing - I need to reset the 'skip' parameter to 0 for the new filter search as the pagination values from the previous search won't be valid or applicable. Is there a way I can change:

```
skip=20
```

to:

```
skip=0
```

as part of this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a RegExp replace on the URL:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/((?:\?|&)skip)=\d+/, '$1=0') + '...';
```

(untested)

Note that you should do the same with the productType because otherwise you'll add it again and again.

Better solution would possibly be to have a base URL and then add all necessary parameters instead of doing search and replace...

Answer (score 1):

You can get the query from the URL by splitting the URL using `?`

This will give you the base url in the first index and the query in the second.

You can then get the query parameters by splitting the query using `&`.

You can loop through all of the parameters checking if it is the `skip` parameter. If the parameter is the skip parameter push your new value to an output array. Otherwise push the unchanged parameter to an output array.

You can then use `join` to join all of your output elements using `&` to reconstruct the query and return your original base url with your new query string.

```html
<script>

function fixQuery(qstr) {
    var parts = qstr.split('?');
    var query = parts[1];
    var a= query.split("&");
    var out=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        
        var b = a[i].split('=');
        if(decodeURIComponent(b[0])=="skip")
        {
          out.push("skip=0")
        }
        else {
          out.push(a[i]);
        }
    }
    return parts[0] + '?' + out.join("&");
}
var result= fixQuery("http://example.com/findProducts.php?param1=test+thing&param2=hello&skip=10");
console.log(result)
//http://example.com/findProducts.php??param1=test+thing&param2=hello&skip=0
</script>
```